# How do I make the checkbox checked when loading data from .csv file

Tags: data-loader, data-import, checkbox

I am trying to populate a check box in a custom object with "checked" (True/1) using Apex Data Loader v 32.0.0 in command line mode. I have tried all values documented => True, TRUE, YES, Y & 1 but it still shows as false and the GUI is not getting chekced. Please suggest me the solution/right value in .csbv file so that the checkbox is populated with 1/True and get it checked.

Comment: Check if that column in your csv file is correctly mapped with custom check box field in sf

Comment: turns out that there is trigger that turns the check box value to false; data loader was working; verified by turning the trigger off; thanks

Comment: Are you doing TRUE or "TRUE"?

Comment: Closing this question as off-topic because it's highly unlike to be of use to anyone. The situation was specific to OP's org.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest abandoning the command line loader and use the data import wizard native in the platform.  May be a problem with the loader.

Comment: I need to load the files daily without any manual intervention and files are coming from a SharePoint site to a cloud server. my command line scripts are running from cloud server and wizard (or dataloader.io for that matter) is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of uploading users, I use the value "FALSE" for IsActive, which is a checkbox.